# Static initialization of a map with a pair

Tags: c++, c++11

I'm trying to statically initialize a map that contains a pair:

```
typedef map<int, pair<int, int>> mytype;
static const mytype mymap = { 3, {3, 0} };
```

I'm using Visual Studio 2013, but I get the error:

```
 error C2440: 'initializing' : cannot convert from 'initializer-list' to 'std::map<int,std::pair<int,int>,std::less<_Kty>,std::allocator<std::pair<const _Kty,_Ty>>>'
```

Any idea what would cause this? I thought VS2013 had this C++11 functionality.

Answer (score 14):

You're missing one set of braces:

```
static const mytype mymap = { { 3, {3, 0} } };
                            ^ ^    ^ 
                            | |    pair<int,int> (value)
                            | pair<const key, value> (map element)
                            map<key, value>
```

Comment: Illustrating it like that is hugely helpful, I think.

Answer (score 1):

The compiler thinks you want to initialize the map with two elements.

The correct syntax would be:

```
static const mytype mymap = { { 3, {3, 0} } };
```